# How to find specific class when webscraping with bs4?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to code a scraper that scrapes me the product id of a product on a site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stockx.com/de-de/air-jordan-1-retro-high-dark-mocha'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}


r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

soup.find('div', {'class':'detail'})
print(soup)
```

I want to access the class="detail", but when executing this it gives me the html of the whole site?
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What went wrong**

- You assigned `soup` like this `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')` so it is printing the whole html
- You wanted to do assigning and printing the detail element :
  `detail = soup.find('div', {'class':'detail'})`

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stockx.com/de-de/air-jordan-1-retro-high-dark-mocha'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}


r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

detail = soup.find('div', {'class':'detail'})
print(detail)
```

Comment: very nice, thank you! But whats the problem with my code above?

Comment: @VenomVenom: Take a look at **What went wrong** in my answer.

Comment: Oh, now i get it. I just have to create another element for the detail. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, i will. Just StackOverflow allows it in 10mins